# Bass notes on the treble scale (wavy lines)

Tags: notation

Could someone please assist with an explanation of these wavy lines in the bass with notes moving up to the treble scale? I am not sure how to interpret this information.

Anastasia - P.F. Webster, Alfred Newman

[image: wavy-lines-from-f-piano-score] *

### vs

[image: no-wavy-lines]

Comment: Please add what piece/composer these are from.

Comment: Meter? Clefs? Is the bottom one with triplets and four slur lines a separate piece, another edition, something you notated?

Comment: A distinction I think none of the answers will cover - the top notation is lightly implied to involve both hands, while the bottom notation is similarly implied to involve the left hand only.

Comment: More than LIGHTLY implied I think!

Answer (score 3):

The first example is 8ths, in 12/8 time (or possibly triplets in 4/4, well enough established for the numbers to be omitted) slurred in six-note groups. The wavy lines are one way of writing a slur that crosses between staves.

The second is triplet 8ths, in 4/4 time, slurred in three-note groups.

The first might have been written like this.  Not as pretty?

[image]

Comment: There's not enough information to presume 12/8 time. It could be 4/4 with the triplets already well established and so not explicitly notated as such. 12/8 *feel* would be fair, though that would apply to both exceprts.

Comment: OK, I'll give you that.  Though I bet you can't quote an example other than the 'Moonlight'!

Comment: Schubert Impromptus in C minor, Eb major, Gb major, and both in Ab major.  Chopin Nocturnes Op 15/1, 27/1, 32/2, 48/2, and 72/1. And Moonlight is in cut time, not 4/4. Don't be insulting.

Answer (score 1):

Two different answers.

The top ones are *phrase marks*, meaning the 6 notes, 3 bass, 3 treble are played as one phrase - in one breath if you like.

The bottom are marks to denote *triplets*, 3 notes played in the time of 2.  The number 3 is a giveaway here, sometimes written in the mark, sometimes over. Here, under.

The top and bottom wavy lines are not related to each other in any way.

Comment: On the bottom example I would say the notes also have phrase marks but in groups of 3’s since the triplets are marked on the bottom and triplets are sometimes indicated with simply a number “3”.

Comment: They're both slurs rather than phrase marks I think.   Non-slurred triplets could have a bracket, or have just the number.

Comment: The bottom ones do not denote triplets; that's what the 3s do. The slurs denote legato and phrasing.

Comment: Just legato.  There COULD be an overall phrase mark as well.  But there isn't.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - aren't triplets usually played with 'groups of three' phrasing? I thought that was the point, to differentiate them from quavers in 3/4 time. Unless it's the America thing again.

Comment: @Tim Of course but I was referring to them being slurred together in groups of 3’s as opposed to groups of 6’s in the first image. I see the phrasing marks over the notes as independent of the “3” numbers on the bottom.